# When Requesting a page from ajax and submiting the form that requested page shows nothing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have four options which are single,multiple, matrix and true false kinds of question having value 1-4 respectively in addQuestions.php.Now i have requesting a page through  id using ajax using get method and in that requested page i have given a condition if id ==1 then it will include a file which is singleQuestion.php and so on.Now the problem that has been arises is that in the singleQuestion.php, there are four options with radio buttons. So when the ajax request that files then it shows all the contents of the singleQuestion.php, so whenever i am submitting a form which is in addQuestions.php then it is not retrieving the value of singleQuestion.php inputs. Below are my code:-
addQuestions.php

```
<form action="insertQuestion.php" method="post">
   <select name="selectQuestionType" class="questionInput" onchange='showUser(this.value)' id="selectQuestionType">
           <option value="0" selected>Select Question Type</option>
           <option value="1">Single Choice </option>
           <option value="2">Multiple Choice Question</option>
           <option value="3">Fill in the Blanks</option>
           <option value="4">True False</option>
           <option value="5">Match Matrix</option>
      </select>
<input type="submit" class="button add" value="Save" style="width:auto;" id="addSave" name="myAddSave">
                  <input type="submit" class="button add" value="Save & Next" style="width:auto;" id="saveNext" name="myNextSave">
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

`

```
        function showUser(str)
        {
                if (str=="")
                       {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                          return;
                        } 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                  else
                    {   // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                    {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                      {
                      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                      }
                    }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","getQuestions.php?q="+str,false);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                    }        



                    </script>
                    <div id="txtHint"><b>Question Mode will Be displayed here!.</b></div>
                    <input type="submit" class="button add" value="Save" style="width:auto;" id="addSave" name="myAddSave">
                    <input type="submit" class="button add" value="Save & Next" style="width:auto;" id="saveNext" name="myNextSave">
                    `
```

getQuestions.php

```
    <?php

 $q=$_GET["q"];
if($q==1)
{
    include 'singleQuestion.php';
}
else if($q == 2)
   {

       include 'multipleQuestion.php';
   }

else if($q == 3)
  {
    include 'fillQuestion.php';
  }   
else if($q == 4)
 {
    include 'trueQuestion.php';
 }
else if($q == 5)
 {
     include 'matchQuestion.php';
 }
 else 
  {
        echo 'You Have Not Selected Any Question Type Yet!';
  }


?>
```

In singleQuestion.php

```
<style type="text/css"> .javascript { display: none; } </style>
<?php
    echo $Answer1 = $_POST['Answer1'];
         echo $Answer2 = $_POST['Answer2'];
?>
<br>
<div class="singleContainer">

<div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">A</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1"></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide1" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer1" style="width:600px;padding:7px;"  >
</div> </div>

    <br><br><div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">B</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1" ></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide2" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer2" style="width:600px;padding:7px;" value="joydseep" >
</div> </div>

    <br><br><div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">C</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1"></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide3" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer3" style="width:600px;padding:7px;" >
</div> </div>

    <br><br><div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">D</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1"></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide4" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer4" style="width:600px;padding:7px;"  >
</div> </div>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label style="color:#F1F1F1;">Textbox #1 : </label>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="javascript">your script data to be executed. </div> 
<input type="submit" name="jdb">
</form>

</div>
```

insertQuestion.php

```
<?php
echo $Answer1 = $_POST['Answer1'];
         echo $Answer2 = $_POST['Answer2'];
?>
```

Above are my codes, I'm a newbie in ajax stuffs so i don't know much about ajax that's why i got stucked.Any help would be appreciated much

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="A1">` what you are posting there is no value in input radil

Comment: I recommend to try jquery instead of plane javascript

Comment: I'm trying to posting the value of textbox which are Answer1 to Answer6

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam, the problem is that i already uses many jquery files so i am having a fear that it will not cause conflict.

Comment: then whats the purpose of using radio button

Comment: Use jquery no conflict then.U can do that very easy with jquery ajax

Comment: @YadavChetan, i have not used the radio button yet because it is also not showing the value when submitting the form. If i will be able to get the result then i will used it later on!

Comment: now i got your problem

Answer (score 1):

modify your `singleQuestion.php` according

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['jdb'])){
    echo $Answer1 = $_POST['Answer1'];
         echo $Answer2 = $_POST['Answer2'];
}
else{
?>
<br>
<div class="singleContainer">
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
<div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">A</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1"></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide1" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer1" style="width:600px;padding:7px;"  >
</div> </div>

<br><br><div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">B</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1" ></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide2" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer2" style="width:600px;padding:7px;" value="joydseep" >
</div> </div>

    <br><br><div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">C</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1"></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide3" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer3" style="width:600px;padding:7px;" >
</div> </div>

    <br><br><div class="jdRadio">
<div class="jdRaOne">
    <span class="Answer">D</span><br><br>
    <span class="jdAnswer"><input type="radio" name="A1"></span>
</div>
<div id="Hide4" class="jdText">
    <input type="text" name="Answer4" style="width:600px;padding:7px;"  >
</div> </div>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label style="color:#F1F1F1;">Textbox #1 : </label>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="javascript">your script data to be executed. </div> 
<input type="submit" name="jdb">
</form>
<?php }?>
```

in your code you missed form starting tag

Comment: In the above code, it is of no use :(-> if(isset($_POST['jdb'])){
    echo $Answer1 = $_POST['Answer1'];
         echo $Answer2 = $_POST['Answer2'];
}   I have added it simply to check that if it is showing the value or not.

Comment: then where is your form starting tag?

Comment: it is in addQuestion.php, i have not written my code fully bcoz it contains somewhat of 400 lines. You can assume that it starts from select tag

Comment: oh friend then you should check because without that problem wont solved